# How do I build a server which ensures that client's message is recieved

Tags: apache-kafka

While trying to task to replicate a kafka server, We encountered a problem. We want a server which will receive a message from the producer, If due to some error kafka server doesn't receive the message the producer should send the message again.
One way which we thought was to do ACK. But this will require the producer to have a code block to check for ACK's but we don't want any producer to have to write a extra block of code for it.

Producer should just send the message which it wants to send and end task, It should not check if message was delivered. Kafka server has to see if message has been got or not. If not then do something to get the message back(It can also be running the producer once again)

**How can we achieve this?**

Answer (score 1):

> should not check if message was delivered. Kafka server has to see if message has been got or not

Kafka **does** ack a producer request (if configured). See: [Producer responses](https://kafka.apache.org/protocol#protocol_network) in the protocol, which includes a response with error code, per partition.

There's no way for your client to know it needs to resend a failed event if there's no response from the server upon sending data.

Kafka producer `retries` property defaults to a large value. There shouldn't be any extra code needed